# Getting post meta data, while editing a post in wp-admin panel

Tags: wp-admin, post-meta

is there any chance of getting post meta data while editing post in wp-admin? 
For example -

```
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
```

isn't working, and it won't return post meta data, while editing post. I tried entering value and saving everything, but still it returned nothing.

Comment: Where do you have this code at?  This is a really non-descriptive question.

Comment: Is this in a custom meta box?  If the data is there and the meta key doesn't start with _ it will show up as a custom field.